# uWSGI equivalent for Django-Channels

Tags: django, django-channels

I am aware that Django is request/response cycle and Django Channels is different, my question is not about this.

We know that uWSGI/gunicorn creates worker processes and can be configured execute each request in threads. So that it can serve 10 requests "concurrently" (not in parallel) in a single uWSGI worker process with 10 threads.

Now let's assume that each web client wants to create a websocket using Django Channels, from my limited understanding (with vanilla implementation), that it will process each message in a single thread, which means, to process x amount of connections concurrently, you need x amount of channel worker processes. I know someone will suggest to increase the number of processes, I am not here to debate on this.

My question is simply are there any existing libraries that does similar job with uWSGI/gunicorn that execute consumer functions in threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking for [daphne](https://github.com/django/daphne/). It is mentioned in [channels document](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploying.html#run-interface-servers) itself.

Answer (score 1):

[Daphne](https://pypi.org/project/daphne/) provides an option to scale process [using a shared FD](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/960). Unfortunately, it is not working as expected.

Rightnow, a better alternative is to use [uvicorn](https://pypi.org/project/uvicorn/). You can run multiple workers with

```
$ uvicorn project.asgi --workers 4
```

I have been using this in  production and it seems good enough.

Comment: That seems debatable. I don't see support for anything like channel layers or groups. Seems like you need to build it yourself using your own App class. Its easy enough to set up a socket for each Daphne worker and have Nginx spread out the load. I use HAProxy which allows me to have one socket and any number of workers. I can do deployments without breaking any connections by draining the workers before I restart them though HAProxy.

Comment: Yes. You are right. We can run multiple instances of daphne and load balance using nginx/HAProxy. I was doing that initially. Once I came across unicorn, I tried that and switched to that.